# redis operation with ruby is blocking in ppoll

Tags: ruby, redis

Our project use this [apns provider](https://github.com/o3o3o/apn) that runing on centos 6.4  to push the oofline msg .

The apns provider just read from redis queue with  brpop,  then reformat the data and send to the apns msg to apple push service.

Recently, I faced an problem that the apn provider DO NOT read the msg from redis queue, I just strace the process:

The abnormal strace result:

```
tcp        0      0 ::1:39688                   ::1:6379                    ESTABLISHED 29452/ruby          
[root@server]# strace -p 29452
Process 29452 attached - interrupt to quit
ppoll([{fd=56, events=POLLIN}], 1, NULL, NULL, 8
```

The normal strace result:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {9266059, 349937955}) = 0
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {6, 0})      = 1 (in [8], left {3, 976969})
fcntl64(8, F_GETFL)                     = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
read(8, "*-1\r\n", 1024)                = 5
write(8, "*3\r\n$5\r\nbrpop\r\n$9\r\napn_queue\r\n$1"..., 37) = 37
fcntl64(8, F_GETFL)                     = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
read(8, 0x9a0e5d8, 1024)                = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {9266061, 374086306}) = 0
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {6, 0}^C <unfinished ...>
Process 20493 detached
```

here is the related code:

```
loop do
        begin
          message = @redis.brpop(self.queue, 1)
          if message
              APN.log(:info, "---------->#{message} ----------->\n")
              @notification = APN::Notification.new(JSON.parse(message.last,:symbolize_names => true))

              send_notification
          end
        rescue Exception => e
          if e.class == Interrupt || e.class == SystemExit
            APN.log(:info, 'Shutting down...')
            exit(0)
          end

          APN.log(:error, "class: #{e.class} Encountered error: #{e}, backtrace #{e.backtrace}")

          APN.log(:info, 'Trying to reconnect...')
          client.connect!
          APN.log(:info, 'Reconnected')

          client.push(@notification)
        end
      end
```

This problem occur aperiodically , the period time may be  one or two month.

I think the code logic is right, guess the system network may affect the normal runnning of programming.

When I use pkill [pid] to kill the programm, it just restore the normal condiction starting read the msg from queue.

Now I don't know how to analyse the problem, so I have to use cron to reboot or  send kill signal to the program every dawn periodcally. :(

Can everyone have the idea to handle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You used in your abnormal strace result ppoll with null timeout .
correct way is

```
const struct timespec timeout = { .tv_sec = 10, .tv_nsec = 0 };
struct pollfd myfds;
myfds.fd = fd;
myfds.events = POLLIN;
myfds.revents = 0;
retresult = ppoll(&myfds, 1,&timeout,NULL);
```

This will give 10sec delay once 10sec is finish its return to next code.